# Jacoco gradle 'exclude' not working in Android project with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, jacoco

I have an Android project using kotlin in Android studio and wanted to use Jacoco to report code test coverage. I am using Dagger and I would have liked to exclude those classes from the report. But using `excludes` does nothing and I get errors when I try to run the Jacoco task regarding files that should have been excluded. Below is my `jacoco.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "$versions.jacoco_version"
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    // Grab all build types and product flavors
    def buildTypes = android.buildTypes.collect { type -> type.name }
    def productFlavors = android.productFlavors.collect { flavor -> flavor.name }

// When no product flavors defined, use empty
if (!productFlavors) productFlavors.add('')

productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
    buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->
        def sourceName, sourcePath
        if (!productFlavorName) {
            sourceName = sourcePath = "${buildTypeName}"
        } else {
            sourceName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName.capitalize()}"
            sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}"
        }
        def testTaskName = "test${sourceName.capitalize()}UnitTest"

        // Create coverage task of form 'testFlavorTypeCoverage' depending on 'testFlavorTypeUnitTest'
        task "${testTaskName}Coverage" (type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."

            classDirectories = fileTree(
                    dir: "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${sourcePath}",
                    excludes: ['**/R.class',
                               '**/R$*.class',
                               '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                               '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                               '**/BuildConfig.*',
                               '**/Manifest*.*',
                               '**/*_MembersInjector.*',
                               '**/Dagger*Component.*',
                               '**/Dagger*Subcomponent.*',
                               '**/*Subcomponent$Builder.*',
                               '**/*Module_*Factory.*']
            )

            def coverageSourceDirs = [
                    "src/main/java",
                    "src/$productFlavorName/java",
                    "src/$buildTypeName/java"
            ]
            additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
            sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
            executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")

            reports {
                xml.enabled = true
                html.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of an error:

```
/***/***/StudioProjects/***/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/***/***/App_MembersInjector.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
@Generated(
 ^
  symbol: class Generated
```

That file should be excluded but it is not.

**UPDATE:**

Upon further investigation, it seems that the error is also caused when I try to simply run test from terminal with no jacoco involved, so it might be something deeper than this.

Answer (score 0):

I use like this and work like a charm:

```
task "${testTaskName}Coverage" (type:JacocoReport,
      dependsOn: ["$testTaskName"]
  ) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."
def excludes = [
        '**/R.class',
        '**/R$*.class',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        'android/**/*.*',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
        '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
        '**/Lambda$*.class',
        '**/Lambda.class',
        '**/*Lambda.class',
        '**/*Lambda*.class',
        '**/*Module.*',
        '**/*Dagger*.*',
        '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
        '**/Dagger*Component*.class',
        '**/Dagger*Subcomponent*.class',
        '**/*Subcomponent$Builder.class',
        '**/*Module_*Factory.class',
        '**/*MyCustomStuff*.*'
    ]

    classDirectories.from = fileTree(
        dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${sourcePath}",
        excludes: excludes
    ) + fileTree(
        dir: "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${sourceName}",
        excludes: excludes
    )

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        "src/main/java",
        "src/$productFlavorName/java",
        "src/$buildTypeName/java"
    ]
    additionalSourceDirs.from = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories.from = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData.from = files([
        "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec"
    ])
}
```

Comment: Tried it, similar error to what i posted in my question (updated it with an error example).

Comment: try this:
 executionData.from = files([
        "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec"
replace this line with following line
executionData ["$testTaskName"].destinationFile

Comment: @AdrianSicaru i usually get this error when i switch branches that some class is not there but the generated are. Did you try clean / build it?

Comment: Thing is your project still needs to build, so for me this looks that is not related to jacoco at all @AdrianSicaru

Comment: @gmemario I cleaned, rebuilt, invalidated caches and restarted... Other gradle tasks for detekt and ktlint for example, run without issues, and I can run the project just fine. I don't know what else to try.